# C#.NET: Acquire administrator rights?

Tags: c#, security, administrator

Is it possible in a C#.NET application to request administrative rights on a Windows 7 PC?

I want to be able to deploy the application via Click Once and have users use it to perform administrative tasks (in this case it is writing registry entries for the main application).

Comment: Does this address your question? * [Demand UAC elevation for an application by adding a manifest using mt.exe](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) Here is another one that appears to explain the same thing: * [Request UAC Elevation for .NET Application (Managed Code)](http://www.aneef.net/2009/06/29/request-uac-elevation-for-net-application-managed-code/)

Comment: I suppose this was required for VS2005, but with VS2008 (and above, I guess), simply add a new item to your project, select **Application Manifest File** as template. Then edit this file and set `level="requireAdministrator"` as explained in the xml comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-1

http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-2

http://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-3

*self promotion

Extra characters because it must be 30

Comment: [Link-only answers are poor practice on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Links are down.

Comment: @JackGrinningCat fixed

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Links are down again.

Comment: Sorry folks, the links are no longer working. My website went through some transformations and those articles are gone now... But you can find them on web archive https://web.archive.org/web/20160322162954/https://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-1

Answer (score 7):

simply all what you need to do is to add manifest application file 
to your project

simple : right click on the project , add , new item ,  manifest file

---

and Change the

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: You can't publish it then.