# Starting a service programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, windows-services

I'm struggling with starting a service from another application.

Ok, first, that's my starting point:
I got a usual service wrapped into my own class which inherits from ServiceBase.
Furthermore I got a ProjectInstaller instance, which inherits from System.Configuration.Install.Installer and takes care of installing my service on the system in the right way.

it's got these parameters:

```
serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "NameOfService";
serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Manual;
serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalService;
```

This ProjectInstaller output is installed through a usual C# .NET installation project.

The service is shown in the GUI list of services within system control -> administration -> services. But what I'm wondering about is that the service does not appear in the list of services, if I use the cmd.exe and type "net start".

That's waht I have so far. 
Now I want to start my service from another application. This application inherits from

```
ServiceController
```

If I want to call now the

```
Start()
```

method, I get an error telling me that the service could not be opened of the local machine.

I use the same Service Name as stated above. T'm confused about that, because I thought the service is installed correctly through my installer. 
Or does my application (and the cmd.exe too) does not have enough rights to access the service?

Comment: Does the account the application runs under have permissions to start services?

Comment: it's currently the only account on the system having administrator rights, I guess it's allowed to start services, yes. Installing and Starting the service is done using the same account.

Comment: Are you able to start the service manually?

Comment: yes, but only from the user Interface, not from the command line. Starting the service from the command line encounters an error telling me that the access is denied.

Comment: starting the cmd.exe explicit with administrator right works fine. But I hope that there is a way to avoid the need of having administrative rights for starting a service?!

Comment: Then you need to look at accounts and permissions. Access denied points to that.

Comment: hm, ok, maybe I shall point out that i'm using Windows 7. That means i'll have to say explicit using right click "start with administrative rights" that an application has administrative rights. thats a kind of tricky

Answer (score 1):

I found this article on stackoverflow.
I think this answer posted there can be applied here too.

see the link below
[ServiceController permissions in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892088/servicecontroller-permissions-in-windows-7/3892229#3892229)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before, and it was permissions-based for me, too.  I wish that error message was a little more clear.

I'd recommend taking a look at this SO article: [C#.NET: Acquire administrator rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583501/c-net-acquire-administrator-rights) - it looks like there's a good tutorial about upgrading to administrative rights provided in the answers.

Comment: thanks for your post! i found an answer in another question asked on stackoverflow