# How do I lock and force the user to re-enter one's windows password?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-shell, user-accounts

I want to lock the accessing of current operating user, as if the user

clicked on Start → pointed to shutdown → click on LOCK

How to do that in C#?

Comment: You can make an application that runs the following command line. No Dll imports involved here. http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/how-to-lock-your-computer-using-command-line

Comment: Are you trying authorize the user? Maybe as an admin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583501/c-net-acquire-administrator-rights

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jessn.blogspot.com/2009/05/lock-my-computer-programatically-in-c.html  This article says it best:

> A much better design that isn't hard coded to your windows system
>   paths, etc:
>
> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>
> [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern void LockWorkStation();
>
> Then just call LockWorkStation();

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown.exe -l");





      it will LOG OFF your computer and now if the account has secure with some password then windows will ask for password otherwise not.
```