# attempted to perform an unauthorized operation c# registry

Tags: c#

i want to change the browsers home page using c# application

and i know that in internet explorer i must change the registry
and i use this code

```
 RegistryKey startPageKey = 
     Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main",
     RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,RegistryRights.WriteKey);
     startPageKey.SetValue("Start Page", "http://stackoverflow.com");
     startPageKey.Close();
```

but this error occurs:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
       at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value, RegistryValueKind valueKind)
       at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Users\eng-mayer\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 37
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in D:\Users\eng-mayer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Do you need elevation to change reg?

Comment: this is the exact exeption
{"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation."}

Answer (score 0):

> -http
>
> > ://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-1/
> >
> > ://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-2/
> >
> > ://victorhurdugaci.com/using-uac-with-c-part-3/

@[C#.NET: Acquire administrator rights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583501/c-net-acquire-administrator-rights)

Hope this helps!