# Run method as administrator

Tags: c#, winapi

Is it possible to run method of class as administrator from process started without administrator privilegies?

For example, I have a method:

```
void BeginTransfer(string from)
{
//...
}
```

I need to ask user for administrator privilegies for run this method. Something like total commander ask before copy files to system disk or program files folder.
I trying to use `PrincipalPermission` attribute but it not works for me:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
```

it throws an exception: `Failure to request permissions for the account holder` (translated from russian)

So what I doing wrong?

Comment: or duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583501/c-net-acquire-administrator-rights/3583644#3583644